# How can I remove hidden input languages in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, input-languages, language-pack

When I try to change my input language, I get 4 choices.

But when I actually enter the settings, I see only 2 choices.

Here are some screenshots that will show you the difference choices I get base on which options I enter.

How can I remove the 2 "extra" languages in all places?

**1.**

[image]

**2.**

[image]

**3.**

[image]

**4.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can try to do as described [[here]](https://superuser.com/questions/1256633/windows-10-remove-keyboard-layout-for-chinese) :

- Add the language you want to remove
- Once added, go check if the **input method** for this language is the same as the one you want to remove (this is the tricky thing)
- (If it is not, add the following **input method** that you want to remove)
- Then delete the input method and the language
- Reboot

It worked for me when I wanted to get rid of my chinese input (without chinese language being installed)