# Windows 10 : remove keyboard layout for chinese

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, chinese

I have an annoying issue, quite similar to [[this one]](https://superuser.com/questions/957552/how-to-delete-a-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10.)

The difference here is that I have a language entry for chinese when I want to swich between keyboard layout (french, english, and this bloody chinese). I want to remove the chinese entry, since I uninstalled the software for this (Sogou). But in the available languages from the windows language panel, I only have french and english. I tried to add a chinese layout and remove it, without success.

Here some pictures describing my issue : https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9vxJ.jpg

(Sorry for dirty link, I don't have enough reputation points for more than 2 links)

Any lead would be appreciated, thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, check if you can remove Keyboard under this setting:

Go to systray and open Language preferences. Click Options for each language that has an extra kayboard that you want to remove.

In Keyboards section click Add a keyboard and select a keyboard that appears in your systray and which you want to remove. This adds a new input option for the selected language. After you add the keyboard, click it and click on a Remove button. After that, the keyboard should disappear also from systray.

If the issue still persists, You can remove the entry directly from Windows registry. Under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Keyboard Layouts, it is probably at the end of the list. Mine looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Indeed it finally worked ! Thanks a lot !
The details I add to figure out was to :
1) Be careful about the input name (not only the language name)
2) Reboot between adding the inputs and language and removing it